# PAW change to light theme?

Tags: paw-app

Does anyone know how to change PAW 3.15 theme from Dark to Light/White? I have tried looking in PAW>Prefs and View menus and do not see how you can change it to the light theme.

thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Prefs > General > Switcher at the bottom.

[Theme switcher in preferences](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nhB7E.png)

Or in Window menu:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVFnH.png)